# Query with tricky group by

Tags: sql

Help me please, I have table like that:

```
id1, id2, quantity
1    1    5
2    1    3
3    1    0
2    3    10
1    3    4
```

All I need is to get id1 and id2 values where quantity is max grouped by id2.
please, help me.

First id - it's id where good (id2) is located. Q - q per warehouse. Perfect result would be like that:

```
id1, id2, quantity
1    1    5
2    3    10
```

Or something like that. I need to know id of product (id2) and id of storage (id1) with MAX quantity among other storages with such product. Also result MAX(q) nice to get.

Comment: And what would the results be?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.*
from t
order by quantity desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

This fetches the row with the highest quantity.  Or this?

```
select t.*
from t
where t.quantity = (select max(t2.quantity) from t t2 where t2.id2 = t.id2);
```

Comment: Thank for your anser, let me think about it.

Answer (score 0):

So, I am a bit misunderstand something. I guess there is an answer:

```
SELECT id1, id2, q FROM temp 
WHERE q IN (SELECT MAX(q) FROM temp GROUP BY id2)
```

I just get rows with MAX(q) values of quantity.